# Using Bootstrap, how do I position labels to the left of the input box when there are multiple inputs on the same row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row with three inputs, two of the inputs have labels to their left. What is happening is the label is being displayed on top of the input box rather than to the side, like so:

[image]

Here is what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

```
        <div class="row">
            <div data-bind="foreach: items" class="padding-left-lg">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Description,valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label class="control-label">
                        Quantity: <input type="text" data-bind="value: Quantity,valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" class="form-control"/>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Units,valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
    <form class="row form-horizontal">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 


       <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </form>
```

Here is the fiddle I made https://jsfiddle.net/g3e8yjyg/.

What is different from the default Bootstrap example? You treat your form as a row or a set of rows, and each formgroup becomes a cell, where you will only vary the value of the size. This will allow you to put many fields in a single row.

```
<form class="row">
    <!--Columns -->
    <div class="col-lg-*"> 
        <!--Your form group in here -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <!--The elements of you formgroup treated as col divs-->  
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-lg-*">Your label</label>
            <div class="col-lg-*">
              <input name="my-input">
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <!--Columns -->
    <div class="col-lg-*"> 
        ...
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `form-inline` class to your form, add the `form-group` class to the containing div, and move the input tag out of your label tag:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <label class="control-label">Quantity:</label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Quantity,valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" class="form-control"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works as far as the label is concerned, but the left most input does not grow when I increase the column size: